# Grid doesn't add up, bumps to next line

Tags: html, css, grid, fluid

I basically copy-pasted the HTML & CSS from a course at TreeHouse and tweaked it myself to accommodate 10 columns (instead of 12) in a 1000px container, and changed them to percentages.

It was fine before I changed it 10 columns, so it might be my calculations that's off. But I'm pretty sure that the numbers are correct.

http://theailona.com/alpha/ or http://cdpn.io/HjiKt

Mind lending me a pair of fresh eyes? :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `display: inline-block` to your `.grid_2` and `.grid_8` classes.

By default display is set to block. Which makes each div take up it's own line.

Here's an image
[image: blocks #2,3,4 are <code>display: block</code>, while the inline blocks are lined up in the same line]

blocks #2,3,4 are `display: block`, while the inline blocks are lined up in the same line

Comment: Thanks! That seem to do the trick, but initially it was fine even if it was display: block. That was before I changed it 10 columns. I added inline-block to grid 2, 3, 7 and 8 but somehow the #slideshow is leaning to the left. It's supposed to line up with the right border.